# Can QML be used to connect local networks?

Tags: networking, qml, local-network

I am working on an application in which I need to send data to another PC in the same network. Is this possible using QML? Any guidance or sample code will be quite helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You want to send data with which technologies (FTP, Samba, HTTP ) ?

Some example with HTTPUploader, i think he can helping you:

https://code.google.com/p/qml-http-uploader/

Comment: Will check that out and see if there's some positive outcome. Thanks!